# Yii cron Propriété localId not define

Tags: php, yii, cron

i try to do a cron on my server but when i call www.mysite.com/cron i have this error :

```
exception 'CException' with message 'La propriÃ©tÃ© Â« CConsoleApplication.localeID Â» est indÃ©finie.' in /home/www/d82da705b703d092a63441c7d4c7c9a3/web/protected/yii/framework/base/CComponent.php:174 Stack trace: #0 /home/www/d82da705b703d092a63441c7d4c7c9a3/web/protected/yii/framework/base/CModule.php(483): CComponent->__set('localeID', 'ch') #1 /home/www/d82da705b703d092a63441c7d4c7c9a3/web/protected/yii/framework/base/CApplication.php(144): CModule->configure(Array) #2 /home/www/d82da705b703d092a63441c7d4c7c9a3/web/protected/yii/framework/YiiBase.php(128): CApplication->__construct('/home/www/d82da...') #3 /home/www/d82da705b703d092a63441c7d4c7c9a3/web/protected/yii/framework/YiiBase.php(116): YiiBase::createApplication('CConsoleApplica...', '/home/www/d82da...') #4 /home/www/d82da705b703d092a63441c7d4c7c9a3/web/cron.php(7): YiiBase::createConsoleApplication('/home/www/d82da...') #5 {main}
```

this is my cron.php file:

```
> $yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/yii/framework/yii.php';
> 
> $config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/productionCron.php';
> defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
> 
> require_once($yii); // creating and running console application
> Yii::createConsoleApplication($config)->run();
```

this is the config/productionCron.php

```
`<?php
return array(
        'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
        'name'=>'Cron',
        'preload'=>array('log'),
        'sourceLanguage'=>'fr',
        'language'=>'fr',
        'localeID'=>'ch',
    'import'=>array(
            'application.components.*',
            'application.components.validators.*',
            'application.components.rewriteRules.*',
            'application.models.*',
            'application.models.abstract.*',
            'application.models.base.*',
            'application.models.behaviors.*',
            'application.models.tabs.*',
            'application.views.widgets.*',
            'application.views.widgets.button.*',
            'application.views.widgets.input.*',
            'application.views.widgets.zii.*',
            'ext.behavior.*',
            'ext.file.*',
            'ext.mail.*',
            'ext.menus.*',
            'ext.menus.base.*',
            'ext.widgets.*',
            'zii.widgets.*',
            'zii.widgets.grid.*',

    ),

    'components'=>array(
            'mail' => array(
                    'class' => 'ext.mail.YiiMail',
                    'transportType' => 'php',
                    'viewPath' => 'application.views.mail',
                    'logging' => true,
                    'dryRun' => false
            ),
            'pathManager'=>array(
                    'class'=>'PathManager',
                    'baseUrl'=>$baseUrl,
            ),
            'log'=>array(
                    'class'=>'CLogRouter',
                    'routes'=>array(
                            array(
                                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                                    'logFile'=>'cron.log',
                                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                            ),
                            array(
                                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                                    'logFile'=>'cron_trace.log',
                                    'levels'=>'trace',
                            ),
                    ),
            ),
            'widgetFactory'=>array(
            ),
            'db'=>array(
                    ...
            ),
            'db2'=>array(
                    ...
            ),
        ),
);`
```

and the cronjobCommand.php

```
class CronJobCommand extends CConsoleCommand {
    public function run($args) {
        echo "Yess";
    }
}
```

If sb has some idea...

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `localeID` isn't a valid attribute. Check here to see what's available: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-application.html

I recommend saving that value somewhere else, maybe in `$params` ? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-module.html#$params-detail